# Java HashMap is unexpectedly "null"

Tags: java

I am making a project work for my Java courses. I wrote a TicTacToe program, but I didn`t checked all methods, but only put method and sort method. I have a null HashMap instead of 1 in it.

This is what I have in the console:

```
Input your column
1
Input your row
1
```

null (ticTacToe.toConsole();)

Where is a mistake?

TicTacToe test class:

```
package TicTac;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacToeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        TicTacToe ticTacToe = new TicTacToe();
        System.out.println("Input your column");
        int column = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input your row");
        int row = scanner.nextInt();
        ticTacToe.selection(column,row);
        ticTacToe.toConsole();
     }
}
```

And main **TicTacToe** class:

```
package TicTac;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TicTacToe {
     HashMap<Integer, String> board = new HashMap<>();
     public void selection(int column, int row) {
         String xOrO = "x";
         if (column == 1 && row == 1) {
         board.put(1,xOrO);
        } else if (column == 1 && row == 2) {
            board.put(2,xOrO);
        } else if (column == 1 && row == 3) {
            board.put(3,xOrO);
        } else if (column == 2 && row == 1) {
            board.put(4,xOrO);
        } else if (column == 2 && row == 2) {
            board.put(5,xOrO);
        } else if (column == 2 && row == 3) {
            board.put(6,xOrO);
        } else if (column == 3 && row == 1) {
            board.put(7,xOrO);
        } else if (column == 3 && row == 2) {
            board.put(8, xOrO);
        } else if (column == 3 && row == 3) {
            board.put(9,xOrO);
        }
         else {
            System.out.println("Wrong data");
        }
    }

     public void checker() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
             if (board.get(1).equals(board.get(2)) && 
 board.get(2).equals(board.get(3))){
            System.out.println(board.get(1) + " player won!");
        } else if (board.get(4).equals(board.get(5)) && board.get(5).equals(board.get(6))){
            System.out.println(board.get(4) + " player won!");
        } else if (board.get(7).equals(board.get(8)) && board.get(8).equals(board.get(9))) {
            System.out.println(board.get(7) + " player won!");
        } else if (board.get(1).equals(board.get(4)) && board.get(4).equals(board.get(7))) {
            System.out.println(board.get(1) + " player won!");
        } else if (board.get(2).equals(board.get(5)) && board.get(5).equals(board.get(8))) {
            System.out.println(board.get(2) + " player won!");
        } else if (board.get(3).equals(board.get(6)) && board.get(6).equals(board.get(9))) {
            System.out.println(board.get(3) + " player won!");
        } else if (board.get(1).equals(board.get(5)) && board.get(5).equals(board.get(8))) {
            System.out.println(board.get(1) + " player won!");
        } else if (board.get(3).equals(board.get(5)) && board.get(5).equals(board.get(7))) {
            System.out.println(board.get(3) + " player won!");
        }
    }
}

public void toConsole(){
    for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(board.get(i));
    }
}

}
```

Comment: what are your inputs for the program and what is the output on your console? Additionally, String should be presented in double quotes. Then, for instance, board.put(9,xOrO); should be changed to board.put(9,"xOrO");

Comment: What sort of error are you getting? Put the error and the code associated to the error. You cannot expect people to go through the entire code and tell you what is wrong with it...

Answer (score 1):

Your toConsole method logic is incorrect. You are trying to get the element at `0` key from `HashMap` whereas the `HashMap` has object at `1` key.

change toConsole method something like below:

```
public void toConsole() {
        for(Entry<Integer, String> entry : board.entrySet()) {
           System.out.println("key = "+entry.getKey() + ", Value = "+entry.getValue());
        }

    }
```

Please read some basics around HashMap implementation at [HashMap docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your `toConsole()` function you have loop that starts at index 0. Board size is 1 at that moment. So the loop prints out result of `board.get(0)` and ends.

Comment: I have this in my loop i < board.size()

Comment: Yes. So your loop is `for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)`. Variable i is 0 in first iteration. Then the loop ends because i == 1 in next iteration.